# set Jquery AJAX properties with javascript object

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am making a call in jquery ajax and while the same code when defining the ajax properties 'from scratch' works, when setting the same values in a javascript object and then define the ajax request with the properties of the object respectively in the server i can't access them.
While this works:

```
    var onsuccess =function (data){
        console.log(data)
        makeArchiveRequest();
    }
    var onerror = function (data){
        console.log(data)
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: 'makeDBEntry/archive',
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data){
            onsuccess(data)
        },
        error:function (data) {
           onerror(data);
        }
    });
```

this doesn't work :

```
    var req = {
        type    :"POST",
        data    : formData,
        url     : 'makeDBEntry/archive',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,

    };

    $.ajax({
        url: req["url"],
        data: req["data"],
        contentType: req["data"],
        processData: req["processData"],
        type: req["type"],
        success: function(data){
            onsuccess(data)
        },
        error:function (data) {
           onerror(data);
        }
    });
```

I just cant figure out what I am doing wrong;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the first version when every thing working fine your having `contentType: false,` , so by simple comparison we notice that in the second one you are setting `contentType: req["data"],` while `req["data"]` has as value `formData` and not `false` . i guess the error is coming from that source.